# Install php tidy to sublime on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, sublime-text

I am using sublime text version build 3059 on ubuntu 14.04. I want to install php tidy in my installed sublime. So can someone tell me how to install php tidy. I am using sublime text for the first time so I don't know how to install plugins and repositories in it. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install plugins, also known as packages, you'll first need to install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). Go to the ST3 [installation page](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and follow the Simple Installation Instructions very carefully. I have not copied the installation code here, as it changes with different releases, however the link I gave should remain constant. Once you've pasted the code into your console and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you've received the confirmation message, quit Sublime completely, then restart it. Basic usage instructions are [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/usage).

---

OK, this is the part where I'd usually tell you to open the Command Palette, find **`Package Control: Install Package`**, scroll through the list, pick `PhpTidy`, and install it easily. Unfortunately, due to the laziness of the author, we can't do it that way, as the Package Control database currently only lists the plugin as working with Sublime Text 2, even though it's been updated (nearly a year ago) to work with ST3. This means we can't install it the usual way. There's also a file in the repository that needs to be deleted, otherwise it may not work. This won't be too hard, so don't get scared, it's just a little command-line work.

First, open up your favorite Terminal emulator. If you installed 14.04 with all the default options, you'll find a button on the top left of the icon toolbar that looks approximately like this:

[image: unity icon]

Click it, and type *"Terminal"* into the search box. The cleverly-named Terminal application should show up, and you can just click on it to open it. If you're a pro command-line user, I apologize for going through this step-by-step :)

**NB: For all the commands below, it would probably be better if you copied them from your web browser and pasted them into Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is the shortcut) instead of trying to recreate them by hand. Even a single-letter mistake could really mess up the process.**

At the command prompt, double-check and see if you have a utility called `git` installed, by typing

```
which git
```

and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If `/usr/bin/git` shows up, great, just skip to the next part. If nothing shows up, or you get a message about installing something, type this next:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and enter your admin user's password when prompted. This will install the utility we need for the next step.

OK, `git` is installed. Next, type

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
```

to change to that directory, which is where certain Sublime Text packages are stored. Then, enter

```
git clone https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimePhpTidy.git PhpTidy
```

to pull the plugin files from Github and place them on your computer in a new `PhpTidy` directory. Finally, type in

```
rm -f PhpTidy/php_tidy.pyc
```

to delete the file that may cause problems for you, and which has no right being in a repo anyways. You can now close Terminal.

---

Congratulations, the plugin is installed! To tidy your PHP code, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Good luck!